# Regarding compartor condition

Tags: java

I have developed below which makes the use of comparator..

this my pojo..

```
  class Emp
{
      String name,job;
      int salary;
      public Emp(String n,String j,int sal)
      {
         name=n;
         job=j;
         salary=sal;
       }
      public void display()
      {
        System.out.println(name+"\t"+job+"\t"+salary);
       }
      public boolean equals(Object o)
      {
          Emp p=(Emp)o;
          return this.name.equals(p.name)&&this.job.equals(p.job)    &&this.salary==p.salary;
       }
       public int hashCode()
       {
          return name.hashCode()+job.hashCode()+salary;
       }  

}
```

this is my user defined collection class of set..

```
  ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
          list.add(new Emp("Ram","Trainer",34000));
          list.add(new Emp("Sachin","Programmer",24000));
          list.add(new Emp("Priyanka","Manager",54000));
          list.add(1,new Emp("Ravi","Administrator",44000));
          list.add(new Emp("Anupam","Programmer",34000));
          list.add(new Emp("Sachin","Team Leader",54000));
          System.out.println("There are "+list.size()+" elements in the list.");
          System.out.println("Content of list are : ");
         ListIterator itr=list.listIterator();
          System.out.println("Sort Object according to Salary");
         Collections.sort(list,new SalaryComparator());
         System.out.println("Content of list are : ");
          itr=list.listIterator();
          while(itr.hasNext())
          {
            Emp e=(Emp)itr.next();  
            e.display();
          }
      }
```

and finally my comparator class

```
class SalaryComparator
  implements Comparator
{
  public int compare(Object paramObject1, Object paramObject2)
  {
    Emp localEmp1 = (Emp)paramObject1;
    Emp localEmp2 = (Emp)paramObject2;
    return localEmp1.salary - localEmp2.salary;
  }
}
```

rite now it is sorting on the basis of salary in increasing order but please suggest me how can I implement the logic in compartor so that first it sort basis of salary and then on the basis of job, that is first salary and then job,Please advise.

Comment: Use an if block. if salaries are equal, then do the next comparison and return the result as -1, 0, or 1 depending on the comparison.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels..could you please explain in detail a little bit , if possible then code it , that will make understanding more clear, thanks a lot

Comment: Btw, you should really read up on generics. You're using raw types, which have been semi-deprecated since Java 1.5 (about 8 years now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always include multiple comparisons in your comparator function.  In this case:

```
class SalaryComparator
  implements Comparator
{
  public int compare(Object paramObject1, Object paramObject2)
  {
    Emp localEmp1 = (Emp)paramObject1;
    Emp localEmp2 = (Emp)paramObject2;
    int salaryDiff = localEmp1.salary - localEmp2.salary;
    if (salaryDiff != 0) {
      return salaryDiff;
    } else {
      if (localEmp1.job == null) {
        if (localEmp2.job == null) {
          return 0;
        } else {
          return 1;
        }
      } else {
        if (localEmp2.job == null) {
          return -1;
        } else {
          return localEmp1.job.compareTo(localEmp2.job);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This setup of null checking puts Emp instances without a job value at the end of the alphabetical ranking.

Comment: Thanks a lot,please explain in detail , if possible then a little bit of code would help to grasp a more, Thanks a lot

Comment: This looks like just a bit of spoon feeding. @user1380194: before asking for "a little bit of code" do you think you could first take our advice and try it yourself? It won't hurt you, I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generics to make your code more type safe:

```
import java.util.*;

class Emp
// as is

// use Comparator <Emp> 
class SalaryComparator implements Comparator <Emp>
{
    // 'Emp' as param type, no casting or isinstanceof inside
    public int compare (Emp emp1, Emp emp2)
    {
        int diff = emp1.salary - emp2.salary;
        if (diff != 0) return diff; 
        else return (emp1.job.compareTo (emp2.job));
    }
}

public class EmpTest 
{
    public static void main (final String args[])
    {
        // how to use collections generically should be known by now:
        ArrayList <Emp> list = new ArrayList <Emp> ();
        list.add (new Emp ("Ram","Trainer", 34000));
        // ...

        // position 3 - slightly more complicated here ...
        ListIterator <Emp> itr = list.listIterator ();
        // ...
        while (itr.hasNext ())
        {
                // but simpler here:
            Emp e= itr.next ();  
            e.display ();
        }
    // here you could use the simplified for-loop:
    for (Emp e : list)
    {
        e.display ();
    }
    }
}
```